# Move validation message to a new place

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
<p class="section requiredtext">some text<br />
<textarea class="title required" id="foo" name="foo"></textarea>
</p>
```

How do i get jquery validate to show the "required field" error message on the same line as the "some text" title. I tried a few things, but I cant get it right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.prependTo(element.parent());
    }
});
```